# Different results for Active Directory "memberof" on different computers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, active-directory

I have some code that retrieves the Active Directory groups that a user is a member of. On localhost it returns the correct results, but when deployed to a another computer (web server on same network) it returns much less results.

I am specifying AD server and a special user name and password I was given by administrators to access.

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://***:389", "***", "***");
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
ds.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(samaccountname=" + search + "))";
ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("*");
SearchResult rs = ds.FindOne();
if (rs != null)
{
    if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["memberof"].Value != null)
    //rest of code removed
```

I also tried a different method and the results were also different...

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "***, "***", "***"))
{
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, name);
    if (user != null)
    {
        List<string> groups = new List<string>();
        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups2 = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
        //rest of code removed
```

I would have thought that by specifying a user name and password that the result should be the same. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

These are different because they're retrieving different datasets. The `memberOf` attribute is constructed on the fly and it will give you the groups the user is a /direct/ member of. The `GetAuthorizationGroups()` call, on the other hand, will give you all the security groups that the user is transitively a member of. It does this by looking at the `tokenGroups` attribute in AD.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. If I run those same two pieces of code on localhost and a web server, they return different results depending on the server.

Comment: Are they different security contexts? Have a look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/331951. It's dated but fundamentally there are permissions requirements to read some of this data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am querying on both servers using the same AD account, or does the computer itself matter?